# How to avoid for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to generate random sample of `partners` with no duplicate in location for 100 iterations. Partners and their locations are in `df`. At the end of each iteration I would like to know the share and ratings for each partners assigned randomly combined with previous data `old_df`

```
# Data
import pandas as pd
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['Hyderabad', 'Assam', 'Kolkata'], 
                      'partner':['x','y','z'],
                      'share':[0.1,0.4,0.2],
                      'ratings':[20,20,10]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['Bangalore', 'Bangalore', 'Mumbai','Mumbai','Mumbai','Pune','Pune','Pune','Chennai','Chennai'], 
                      'partner':['x','y','z','y','z','x','y','z','z','x'],
                      'share':[0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1],
                      'ratings':[20,10,10,20,30,20,20,20,10,20]})
# Simulation
simulations = 100
all_stats = []
start_time = time.time()
for num in range(simulations):
    random_sample = df.sample(frac = 1.0).groupby('location').head(1)
    random_sample = old_df.append(random_sample[['location','partner','share','ratings']])
    condn = random_sample.groupby(['partner']).sum().reset_index()
    condn = condn[['partner','share','ratings']]
    all_stats.append([num,
                      condn.share[0].round(2),
                      condn.share[1].round(2),
                      condn.share[2].round(2),
                      random_sample['ratings'].sum().round(0)])
    all_stats

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (round(time.time() - start_time,3)))
```

For 100 iterations it is taking `1.4seconds`. As I scale up (more data) I would like to run for more iterations, is there any faster way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? There are some very inefficient things you're doing here, like grouping and rounding the same data every iteration, or sampling everything (frac=1) and then taking the first item, rather than just sampling one item (n=1). Also try using a dictionary for variables rather than messing with locals().

Comment: I've edited the code based on comments. Basically I need to create random sample of partners available for the location and summarize ratings and share for each partner for each iteration.

Comment: if you clarify what you're trying to *accomplish* in the question, I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: @anon01 I've edited my question for better clarity

Comment: why are you only sampling the first `groupby("location").head(1)` ?

Comment: @anon01 there should not be any duplicates in location, that's why.